# ActiveMQ Authorization - How To Read Authorization Entries from Database

Tags: authorization, activemq-classic, customization

I am in a process of deploying ActiveMQ with custom Authentication and Authorization. I have a query regarding custom authorization map.

**Question**
I want to have the authorization entries read from database rather than activemq.xml. We don't want to write our authorization entries in activemq.xml file. I don't want to change the wildcard queue name hierarchies as provided in default authorization plugin. 
What code components do I need to re-write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my above question. I only need to interface my custom class so that I am able to load authorization entries from a  source other than activemq.xml. And I can also re-load my authorization every 1 minute so that If a new role or authorization entry is made, it gets reloaded in to the system without restarting.

**Solution Configurations**

1. Create a class that interface AuthorizationMap.
          In my case I extended my class from DefaultAuthorizationMap.java. I
   want similar functionality and want to change only the input of authorization entries. My code reads roles from a database. Refer to section "Code-CustomAuthorizationMap" below.
2. Configure CustomAuthorizationMap class as bean in activemq.xml

   ```
   <plugins>
       <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq"/>

       <authorizationPlugin>
           <map>
               <bean xmlns="" class="com.test.CustomAuthorizationMap"
           </map>
       </authorizationPlugin
   </plugins>
   ```
3. Add lib to classpath

   ```
   a. Create the jar file. Place it in "%ActiveMQ-Home%/lib" folder. E.g. custom-authorization.jar
   b. Modify "%ActiveMQ-Home%/bin/activemq.bat".
      **Replace** 
          set ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%;%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/conf;%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/conf;%ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH%;
      **With**
          set ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%;%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/conf;%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/conf;%ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH%;%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/lib/custom-authorization.jar;
   ```

### Code-CustomAuthorizationMap

```
package com.test.authorization.map;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTempQueue;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic;
import org.apache.activemq.filter.DefaultDestinationMapEntry;
import org.apache.activemq.filter.DestinationMapEntry;
import org.apache.activemq.security.AuthorizationEntry;
import org.apache.activemq.security.DefaultAuthorizationMap;

public class SecGwAuthorizationMap extends DefaultAuthorizationMap {

    public SecGwAuthorizationMap() throws Exception {
        super();

        List<DestinationMapEntry> authorizationEntries = 
       loadAuthorizationEntriesFromPropFiles();

//  For information. After loading I populate 
//authorization entries like below
//          AuthorizationEntry entry = new AuthorizationEntry();
//          entry.setTopic(">");
//          entry.setAdmin("admins");
//          entry.setRead("admins");
//          entry.setWrite("admins");
//          authorizationEntries.add(entry);

//          entry = new AuthorizationEntry();
//          entry.setQueue(">");
//          entry.setAdmin("admins");
//          entry.setRead("admins");
//          entry.setWrite("admins");
//          authorizationEntries.add(entry);

//          entry= new AuthorizationEntry();
//          entry.setTopic("ActiveMQ.Advisory.>");
//          entry.setAdmin("gcabrokerusers,admins,users");
//          entry.setRead("gcabrokerusers");
//          entry.setWrite("gcabrokerusers");
//          authorizationEntries.add(entry);

//          entry = new AuthorizationEntry();
//          entry.setQueue("gcaa.test.jms.>");
//          entry.setAdmin("gcabrokerusers");
//          entry.setRead("gcabrokerusers");
//          entry.setWrite("gcabrokerusers");
//          authorizationEntries.add(entry);
            setAuthorizationEntries(authorizationEntries);
        }

    public SecGwAuthorizationMap(List<DestinationMapEntry> 
    authorizationEntries) {

        super(authorizationEntries);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 }
```

Note:- Below is a sample roles.properties files to tell how we are creating authorization roles.

**roles.properties file**

```
//commentedLine      Destination     Read-ACLs    Write-ACLs    AdminAcls     Type
ActiveMQ.Advisory.>::admins,appUsr::admins,appusr::admins,appUsr::TOPIC
test.accounts.queue::appClientId::appClientId::admins::QUEUE
>::admins::admins::admins::QUEUE
>::admins::admins::admins::TOPIC
```